# PHP code if not working

Tags: php

i have a problem
My code is

```
if(isset($_SESSION["steamid"]))
{
   echo' <a href="?login"><button type="button" name="use_button" class="btn btn-warning">Login trough steam</button></a>'; 

}else{

   echo'<form method="POST" action='givadd.php'><button type="submit" name="use_button" class="btn btn-success">Participate</button></form>';
}
```

But somehow it dosent work and page is blank. Maybe someone can help me. thank you.

Comment: I suggest turning on errors and trying to help yourself?  `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(-1);` is a starting point.

Comment: it only work if the above mentioned session is available

Comment: action='givadd.php' change this to action="givadd.php"

Comment: Add double quotes to action.

Comment: Your buttons are also switched or not? Now the login button is visible for users with the session. I don't know if that has to be or not. But if not, you can use `if(!isset($_SESSION["steamid"])) {`

Comment: i have turned on errors, but page is still blank.

Comment: session is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that you used

```
echo '... action='....' ...';
```

Instead of

```
echo '... action="...." ...';
```

Comment: thank you, solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML attributes require double quotes `"` to have their arguments passed, I've corrected this in your form `action=''` to become `action=""`.

You could try it like this, it would also help you to maintain HTML.

```
if(isset($_SESSION["steamid"])) { ?>    
    <a href="?login">
        <button type="button" name="use_button" class="btn btn-warning">
            Login trough steam
        </button>
    </a> 
<?php } else { ?>
    <form method="POST" action="givadd.php">
        <button type="submit" name="use_button" class="btn btn-success">
           Participate
        </button>
    </form>
<?php }
/// Continue your script here...
```

Comment: somehow it dosent work :/ but the problem was solved by user6160675